# Splice first and last 3 digits off a short integer?

Tags: c++, integer, short, splice

I have lots of variables in an array like this: `short num  = 7123;`.  The value is ALWAYS 4 digits long. How to go about turning this into  `a = 7; b = 123;`?

All I can think of is converting to c-string and stripping it off, but doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = num % 1000;
a = num / 1000;
```

Comment: @mcmcc If we're going to be microoptimizing we should add 24, then bitshift right by 10 and avoid divides and modulo altogether... (this is safe because short int can hold more than 4 digits, so no chance of overflow)

Comment: @bdares: That works for a leading 1, but not for larger leading digits...? 7024 >> 10 isn't 7.

Comment: @StilesCrisis humm you're right.  What did I do wrong... Oh, you have to add 24 for each thousand you're bitshifting right by 10.  ... make a lookup table.

Comment: @mcmcc: See my answer for `div()` which saves manually working out the result.

Comment: @bdares:  I expressed it as a optimization but it could also be argued to be a bit clearer in intent, unlike your lookup table (which is likely an anti-optimization anyway).

Answer (score 3):

The C standard library contains `div()` which can do this in one operation:

```
div_t r = div(num, 1000);
a = r.quot;
b = r.rem;
```

The C standard library can be expected to have an optimised implementation of `div()` that will do the division *and* remainder in one machine instruction (on CPUs that have such an instruction).

Answer (score 1):

```
short a = num / 1000; 
short b = num % 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

```
a = num / 1000;
b = num % 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// cast to integer should drop the decimal
a = (int) ( num / 1000 );

// use variable a to subtract the thousand place to zero
b = a - num;
```